# How Reauthenticate User at Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to update the user's email, but firebase requires a recent login for this, so I tried to use the method that was in the firebase documentation, but the problem is how I can pass the password user? I do not keep the password in db, and I can not get it from the firebase, so I do not know how I can pass the password.

The solution I thought is to ask the user to enter the password, so I tried to use a field to enter the password but it still does not work, so how can I pass the password to the firebase and reauthenticate the user to change the data?

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-authenticate a user, referring to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users).

For instance you have a field where the user types his password, let's say it`s an EditText **etPassword**, and you have user email in **SharedPreferences**

So the code to re-authenticate will look like this:

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential(SharedPreferences.getmail(),etPassword.getText().toString());

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
               if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    updateUserEmail();
                 } else { 
                 // Password is incorrect 
                 }
            }
        });
```

where  **updateUserEmail()** is

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day.

Comment: user  types his email and password in my app , isn't it a security breach, i can sent them onto the network without the knowing of the user